# Have those who have been detained from the 2017-2019 Saudi Arabian purge now been released?

Tags: saudi-arabia

[Salman bin Abdulaziz Al saud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salman_bin_Abdulaziz_Al_Saud_(born_1982)) is a famous prince due to his involvement in Dota 2 esports, as he has funded many public tournaments and spent over 30k hours on the game himself as shown his [steam profile. On his [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salman_bin_Abdulaziz_Al_Saud_(born_1982)), it is written he was detained at a result of the 2019 Saudi arabian purge. On the linked reddit of his steam page, it shows that the last post is [two years ago](https://www.reddit.com/user/ArchangelYuji/), that is 2021.

So, did Saudi arabia start releasing the royals who got arrested now? Seems unclear to me since nothing is written on the wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

Some lesser figures probably have been released, but the main opponents of MBS, like [MBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_bin_Nayef) definitely have not. Their detention conditions have in fact [gotten](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/nov/29/mbs-v-mbn-the-bitter-power-struggle-between-rival-saudi-princes) worse in 2020, after the [alleged](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/mar/07/saudi-crown-prince-in-new-purge-with-treason-arrests) coup attempt.

Besides, being officially released doesn't mean all that much in Saudi Arabia. E.g. some of those released found all their house staff replaced with different personnel. Some have enforced residence, even in the royal compounds. There are various formal and informal prohibitions on whom they can contact, etc. E.g. Bakr bin Laden [was](https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/saudi-arabia-bakr-bin-laden-construction-magnate-freed) officially released in 2021, but "told to stay home". The prince you seem ask about [was](https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/saudi-arabia-purge-royals-detained-whereabouts-revealed) revealed in Nov 2021 to have been held incommunicado for over a year, after being beaten until he fell unconscious (the latter according to the expat opposition group DAWN) etc. OTOH he [seems](https://www.tiktok.com/@psalmanalsaud/video/7224233325941034267?lang=en) to have a TikTok account with recent posts.

Comment: BTW, if you read a bit about more ancient (pre-WW2) Saudi history, this is about typical for how they treated some of their [defeated enemies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashidi_dynasty).

Comment: (Some of videos are a bit weird, like [one](https://www.tiktok.com/@psalmanalsaud/video/7121365257666317573?lang=en) posted on 2022-7-17, which shows him giving a talk at some France - Saudi Arabia event, but the speech sound is entirely replaced with music. Those where he speaks in Arabic have their original sound, but I have no idea what he's saying. First post is on 2022-5-10, maybe he was afforded some kind of [partial] rehabilitation then. Or maybe it's just some fan account.)

Comment: There may be some level of concidence between the appearance of that TikTok account and an OHCHR resolution https://www.ohchr.org/sites/default/files/2022-02/A_HRC_WGAD_2021_59_SaudiArabia_AEV.pdf